# How to finish tiling an outside edge for a shower?

Tags: shower, tile, corner-bead

I am installing stone tile (travertine) in a shower. I do not have bullnose tile so I was planning on simply finishing the edge by slightly filing the corners of the tile so they're not sharp and then caulking the edges so the thinset is hidden. Unfortunately I think I'll have to go entirely to the outside corner of the wall because the shower curb goes that far and I want to make sure the shower door will have ample room to be installed without having to deal with the outer edge of the tile being right in the middle of the door installation.

Here is a picture of the wall and curb. When I put on the 1/2" drywall, it should align with how far the curb sticks out.

[image]

1. Should I use some kind of corner bead? Are there any special instructions for that since it's near the wet area? Maybe I can treat it as a dry area since it will be on the opposite side of the shower door?
2. Should I skip the corner bead and instead take the tile all the way to the corner?
3. Can I have a corner bead and take my tile almost to the corner (about 1/2" away)?
4. Does anyone have tips for ending the tile in the 'open' like I am? People have previously suggested using the Schluter edging but I haven't see any that would look good with my tile so I've sort of ruled that out as an option.

(Yes I now realize I should have done the floor before setting the bottom row of tile)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joe, sorry to use the "answer" function again instead of adding another comment, I wanted to attach more pictures.

The tile I used was not available with a bullnose so I finished it flat on the sidewall. The edge cant be seen normally so I did not spend time making it perfect, but for your situation I retract my note about never finishing an edge with caulking. If you end flat to the wall around that corner it would be perfectly fine to use caulking for aesthetic purposes, use paintable caulk so you can paint a straight line down the whole side when you paint the wall.

Sorry I misunderstood your question, my situation was similar to yours and wrapping the tile around to the outside seemed like the best solution for me, and it looks pretty good that way (at least my wife did not complain, that's all that really matters). [image]

Comment: And yes, no special prep outside the shower area. You could glue it right to the drywall if you want.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I was looking for. Appreciate the pics!

Answer (score 1):

You should NOT treat the top of the curb as a dry area, prepare it the same way as you prepare the shower floor (and it should be sloped toward the shower). I think you should tile the whole top and front of the curb [image: like this].

If you cant find a suitable "corner round", you could finish the edge of the tile at the *front* of the curb, or finish the front edge corner (if you choose to tile the front side of the curb, which I recommend) with grout [image: like this].

I do not recommend finishing any tile edge with caulking.

Comment: I'm not treating the top of the curb as a dry area (and it is sloped). I was talking about treating the unfinished wall in my pic as the dry area

Comment: Is the tile in your picture bullnose where it "ends" on your side wall? I can certainly come out of the shower a little bit with the tile